# Which package to use for using bit operator in java?

Tags: java

I'm not able to compile Java code that contains bit operators. Which package should I use?

```
test.java:16: not a statement
      carry << 1;
            ^
1 error
```

Comment: Provide the necessary code to replicate the problem.

Comment: It's called "The Java Language Specification", available off the Oracle web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the result of the operator to a variable

```
int carry = 5;
carry = carry << 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any package for the operation you are performing.
You are not writing a correct statement.
use this :

```
carry = carry << 1;
```